# Is there a way to import multiple repos at once from github into azure devops?

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, devops

I have an organization in github with 100+ repos that I would like to move into azure devops. Right now it seems like I have to manually import each project repo into azure devops. Is there a way for me to pull multiple at once? Thank you.

I have not been able to find anything similar to this online.

Comment: Time to learn bash/Powershell scripting!

Comment: Any working code that you found?. Is these below commands running on gitlab/github cli?

Answer (score 0):

```
$gitHubOrg = "your-github-org"
$azureDevOpsOrg = "your-azdo-org"
$azureDevOpsProject = "your-azdo-project"

gh auth login

$repos = convertfrom-json (& gh repo list $gitHubOrg --json name) 

echo "Migrating these repos: "
echo $repos

az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg

foreach ($repo in $repos)
{
  $repoName = $repo.name
  echo "Migrating repo " $repoName
  & az repos create --name $repoName --organization https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg --project $azureDevOpsProject 
  & git clone --mirror https://github.com/$gitHubOrg/$repoName.git $repoName
  pushd $repoName
  & git lfs fetch --all
  & git remote add azure-devops https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg/$azureDevOpsProject/_git/$repoName
  & git push --mirror azure-devops
  & git lfs push azure-devops --all
  echo "Migrated repo " $repoName
  popd
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

This is relatively easy to script. Use the GitHub cli `gh repo list $orgname` to list all repos in the source. Use `az repos create` to create a new repo in the target org.

```
& gh auth login

$gitHubOrg = "mycompany"
$repos = convertfrom-json -raw (& gh repo list $gitHubOrg --json name) 

& az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg
```

Then use the standard CLI to clone each repo and push it to the remote

```
$azureDevOpsOrg = "myOrg"
$azureDevOpsProject = "myProject"

foreach ($repo in repos)
{
  & az repos create --name $repo --organization https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg --project $azureDevOpsProject 
  & git clone --mirror https://github.com/org/$repo.git $repo
  pushd $repo
  & git lfs fetch --all
  & git remote add https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg/$azureDevOpsProject/_git/$repo
  & git remote add azure-devops
  & git push --mirror azure-devops
  & git lfs push azure-devops --all
  popd
}
```

To push each repo into Azure DevOps.

In case you're connecting to Azure DevOps Server, you need to replace: `https://dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrg` with `https://servername/collectionname`, e.g. `https://tfs.mycompany.com/DefaultCollection` or (if it's an older or upgraded installation) `https://tfs.mycompany.com/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Above example in PowerShell assuming you have the following tools installed:

- [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/)
- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)
- [Azure CLI Azure DevOps extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops)
- [Git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)
- [Git LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases)
- [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases)

Comment: What's with the -1?

Comment: This was a helpful answer. Right now I'm working with an on-prem azure devops server and so I am running in to issues with trying to use the Azure CLI. Will update if I get this to work. Thank you

Comment: In the case of Azure DevOps Server, make sure you connect to `https://server/{collectionname}` for the `az` commands. Worst case you can directly call the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP